# How Can I autofill a form of other application from my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to fill other application form from our application

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unclear. Can you expand, please?

Comment: actually i want to set values from database to other form,which form is not in my application .its already running application form like nuakari.dom registration form

Comment: Where does this database live? Are you a native (Windows desktop? iOS? Android?) application, or a web app? If you're a web app, is client-side integration (with Java, say, on supported platforms) an option?

Comment: its web app,there is any kind of dll in asp.net for doing this functionality

Comment: Browsers typically don't allow activity like this. You're probably out of luck.

Comment: than can any one help me, about how to autopost application work.. like AutoPost JobPosting tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your concern, actually you are looking for some kind of we site scrapping technique. You can do this in the following way:

1. You can use WatiN tool from http://watin.org/
2. You can create a Winform app & use Webbrowser control inside it. Navigate to your desired site. Handle the `Load Complete` event, search the web page controls and set the value. You too can click the buttons programmatically also.

Better use the `WatiN tool` for ease.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to send an HTTP POST request to the remote application endpoint which is used to process the form submit. You could use the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class for that:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    { 
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", "value 1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2", "value 2"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param3", "value 3"),
    });
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var result = client.PostAsync("http://example.com/", content).Result;
    var result.StatusCode;
    var result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Depending on the status code you will know whether the request has succeeded or not.